# Show divergence with Leibniz's criterion for alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Can Leibniz's criterion for alternating series be used to show divergence?

If the test fails, can you conclude that the given series diverges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the hypotheses of the Leibniz criterion is that the $n$-term of the series goes to zero.  If this condition is not satisfied then indeed the series is divergent.

The other condition is that the absolute value of the $n$-th term is a monotone function of $n$.  The failure of this condition does not necessarily imply that the series is divergent.